# How to not incrementing loop counter for invalid input within the loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to write a simple program that will take input using a Scanner and output the lowest number, the highest number, and the average of them all. But I do not want numbers below 0 or greater than 100. I've got the program to output the min, max, and average, and it will tell me if I have entered a number less than 0 or greater than 100, but it still counts it as a "rotation" in the for loop. I basically want the program to return to the previous number instead of continuing forward in the for loop when the wrong number is entered. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ExamGrades {

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in );

        int number = 0;
        double total = 0;
        int minimum;
        int maximum = 0;

        System.out.println("Please enter the first integer: ");

        number = scan.nextInt();
        minimum=number;
        total += number;

        for(int i = 2; i<11; i++){

            if(number<0 || number >100){
                System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
                number = scan.nextInt();
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Please enter integer " + i + ":");
                number = scan.nextInt();
                total += number;

            if(number<minimum)
                minimum = number;
            if(number>maximum)
                maximum = number;
            }
        }

        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        System.out.println("The minimum is: " + minimum);
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + maximum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + oneDecimalPlace.format((total) / 10.0 ));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can decrement the loop counter (the variable i) from inside the for loop; this may not be the best practice, but it will get the job done.

Alternately, you can use a while loop (such as while (i < 11) and increment i only when an acceptable value is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `while()` instead of `for()`:

```
int i = 1;
while(i <= 10){
    if(number < 0 || number > 10) {
        // Code goes here
    } else {
        // More code goes here
        i++; // Notice that i only increments here
    }
}
```

Other option would be a `do... while()` loop, that may help you avoid duplicating code:

```
int i = 1;
do {
    if(i == 1)
        System.out.print("\nEnter first number:\t");
    else
        System.out.print("\nEnter next number: \t");
    number = scan.nextInt();
    if(number < 0 || number > 10) {
        // Code goes here
    } else {
        // More code goes here
        i++; // Again, i only increments here
    }
} while(i < 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change the `if` statement to a `while loop`.

```
for(int i = 2; i < 11; i++){
    System.out.println("Please enter integer " + i + ":");
    number = scan.nextInt();

    while(number < 0 || number > 100){ // Wait for valid input
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
        number = scan.nextInt();
    }

    total += number;
    if(number < minimum) minimum = number;
    if(number > maximum) maximum = number;
}
```

That way you don't progress to another iteration in the `for loop` until there is valid input.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as a while loop instead

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExamGrades {

public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in );

    int number = 0;
    double total = 0;
    int minimum;
    int maximum = 0;
    int I = 2;
    System.out.println("Please enter the first integer: ");

    number = scan.nextInt();
    minimum=number;
    total += number;

    while (I < 11){

        if(number<0 || number >100){
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid number: ");
            number = scan.nextInt();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Please enter integer " + i + ":");
            number = scan.nextInt();
            total += number;

            if(number<minimum)
                minimum = number;
            if(number>maximum)
                maximum = number;
            I++;
            }
        }

        DecimalFormat oneDecimalPlace = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        System.out.println("The minimum is: " + minimum);
        System.out.println("The maximum is: " + maximum);
        System.out.println("The average is: " + oneDecimalPlace.format((total) / 10.0 ));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just decremented i inside the if statement instead. Another question though if you do not mind; When I input numbers less than 0 or greater than 100, it saves that as the min/max. I do not want to save numbers less than 0 or greater than 100 as the min/max. How would I fix it so that it will only save numbers in-between?